# User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an asp.net application with Windows authentication. User.Identity.Name seems to return the logged in user in the form `MACHINENAME\USERNAME`.

I would like to use this to access a database of user specific settings but what happens if the user logs on from a different machine, then the `MACHINENAME` part will be different. So can I simply take the `USERNAME` part and ignore the `MACHINENAME` part? Is the format of User.Identity.Name always `MACHINENAME\USERNAME` for Windows authentication?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More specifically, `User.Identity.Name` returns in the format `[Domain]\[User]`

If your users are showing up as different domains when they access from different machines, then they are in fact different user accounts.  You may be able to strip out the `[Domain]` part, but that means that if anybody on a machine (domain) connects as a user with the same name as a user on a different machine (domain) then the system won't be able to tell them apart.  This may be "fine, for now" in your scenario, but it's definitely not good practice.

Comment: Ah, I see, it is actually `[Domain]\\[User]`, thanks it makes sense now.